# SSIS Populating to multiple table

Tags: sql, ssis

I have these tables on my SQL Server

1. view_items - itemcode, itemname, description, length, width, height, weight
2. items - itemid, itemname, itemcode, description
3. items_specs - itemspecsid, itemid, length, width, height, weight

I tried to import data from my view (**view_items**) to **items** table using **SSIS** with **OLEDB Source** and **OLEDB Destination**. I managed to import it successfully but my problem is that how can I be able to use the inserted **itemid** to be my foreign key to **item_specs** table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need 2 Data flow tasks. The first data flow component would populate the items table as you have done.
The second data flow task would pull the use view_items as the source and then you could use a lookup transformation.[image: Lookup ItemId]

In the columns section you can map based on the uniqueness of the record. For example if your itemname is unique then as below and check the itemid column to be the lookup column.

-[image]

Answer (score 0):

1)This is how I will start:
Turn the identity_insert off on the items table.
Find the max from the items, and increment it by 1. This is your item id for the current row of information retrieved from the view_items. You can use a look up table to store the max id. 
This item id can now be inserted into both items and items_specs
Once done, turn the identity_insert ON

Answer (score 0):

Will this work?
I think you can add a DTF after the 'Items' load with an `OLEDB Source` with the below `Source` script

```
SELECT  IS.itemspecsid, 
        IS.itemid, 
        IS.length, 
        IS.width, 
        IS.height, 
        IS.weight
FROM    items I
JOIN    items_specs IS ON I.itemid = IS.itemid
```